# Could someone explain me the output of "str("Hello") == str("World!")" in R. I was expecting "TRUE"

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm just learning R, and I tried this:
`str("Hello") == str("World!")`

I was expecting an logical output, like TRUE or FALSE, but instead, it returned this:
 `chr "Hello" chr "World!" logical(0)`

I didn't understand why, bacause the str() function should print the class and whatever is inside parenthesis...
Could someone help me in understanding this, please?

Many thanks.

Tried: `str("Hello") == str("World!")`
Expected: "TRUE" or "FALSE"
Reality:
 `chr "Hello" chr "World!" logical(0)`

Comment: `"Hello" == "World!"` gives you a logical output as well as `class("Hello") == class("World!")`.

Comment: `str` returns `NULL`, it is used for its printing side effect only. Maybe you are looking for `capture.output(str("Hello")) == capture.output(str("World!"))`?

Comment: As Rui Barradas wrote, your code equivalent to `NULL == NULL`. You can compare a NULL value with something else with `identical(NULL, ...)`. In your case that would return the expected logical `TRUE`. (Did you mistake `str` with a function to return a **str**ing?)

Comment: No, I was just tring to understand if the str() function works like class() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the following.

```
tmp <- str("Hello") 

print(tmp)
```

is returning:

```
chr "Hello"
NULL
```

So you see that `NULL` is assigned to `tmp`. The same is for `str("whatever")`.

So you are calling :

```
NULL == NULL
```

That's obviously `logical(0)`